# file.separator Java 7 option causes ExceptionInInitializerError

Tags: java, windows, jvm, 64-bit, teamcity

We have a TeamCity (7.0.3) agent running on a 64-bit Windows Server 2008 machine. When we recently upgraded the agent to use Java 7 (1.7.0_10) the builds started failing with the following stacktrace:

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:841)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1084)
    at java.lang.System.initializeSystemClass(System.java:1145)
Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
    at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)
    at java.io.Win32FileSystem.<init>(Win32FileSystem.java:40)
    at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.<init>(WinNTFileSystem.java:37)
    at java.io.FileSystem.getFileSystem(Native Method)
    at java.io.File.<clinit>(File.java:156)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:841)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1084)
    at java.lang.System.initializeSystemClass(System.java:1145)
```

The problem seems to be caused by the inclusion of the "-Dfile.separator=\" java option that TeamCity uses in the executable command for the agent. I was able to reproduce the problem by writing a simple "Hello World" class and compiling it on the Windows box and then running the program with the file.separator option (i.e. java -Dfile.separator=\ HelloWorld)

I haven't found any similar bug reports. Has anyone seen anything like this? Has the behaviour of file.separator changed in Java 7?

Furthermore I realise that \ is the default file.separator for Windows anyway so I don't think the agent really needs to use it in the executable command, however I can't see a way in TeamCity to tell the agent not to include it. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: An ExceptionInInitializerError is thrown to indicate that an exception occurred during evaluation of a static initializer or the initializer for a static variable (see [here](http://www.cin.ufpe.br/~java/docs/langspechtml/javalang.doc.html)). Maybe you're just lacking static blocks.

Comment: Thanks, but that does not apply here. The "Hello World" program that  fails only contains a single main method with a System.out.println.

Comment: use \\ instead? but if this is a new problem on java 7, it might be a bug

Comment: \\ didn't work. It appears to be a problem with update 10, as update 9 works fine. Huff. I'll create a bug report with Oracle.

Comment: TeamCity is affected by this issue too. See [TW-25070](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-25070)

Comment: I can confirm that this is still an issue after updating to Java 7 Update 17 (from 7_11).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks java.exe now trims trailing \ (back-slash).

I have the following code:
    import java.lang.*;

```
public class test {
  public static void main(String[] argz) { 
    for(String s : argz) {
     System.out.println("agg=" + s + "|");
    }

    System.out.println("prop=" +  System.getProperty("prop") + "|");
  }
}
```

I start it with Java 1.7.0_07 and _10:

```
C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\bin\java.exe -cp . -Dprop=z\\ test a\\ b
agg=a\\|
agg=b|
prop=z\\|
```

and _10

```
C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_10\bin\java.exe -cp . -Dprop=z\\ test a\\ b
agg=a|
agg=b|
prop=z|
```

And one more series:

```
C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\bin\java.exe -cp . -Dprop=z\ test a\ b
agg=a\|
agg=b|
prop=z\|
```

and _10

```
C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_10\bin\java.exe -cp . -Dprop=z\ test a\ b
agg=a|
agg=b|
prop=z|
```

Comment: Looks like a bug in JVM, and probably not only TeamCity is affected. Previously if argument ends with \ we did not have to use quotes, command line parser ate this correctly. Now we have to quote such arguments.

Comment: Thanks for the little investigation. I've raised the bug with Oracle against 1.7.0_10, so we'll see what (if anything) happens there.

Comment: GaZ, would you please share the issue link here

Comment: It doesn't appear to be a public-facing bug-tracker, but according to the automated response I received the report was assigned an internal review ID of 2406463. I'll update this thread if I ever hear anything more from them.

Comment: Where did you submit the bug? I'd expect to see it at http://bugs.sun.com/ but it is not there. Did you use http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/ to file that? I'm afraid it is filed somewhere where no one cares...

Comment: Oh, I just filled the same and see I duplicated the effort - they do not make the bug report public until it is reviewed.. So they've got another one under internal #2426425 :) I don't understand why they don't want to publicize those that are waiting for review. Also, I hope that based on the numbers we see, there is not 20k new bug reports per week :)

Answer (score 12):

Try the JVM command line parameter `-Dfile.separator=\/` (i.e., specify both a backward and forward slash).

Comment: This seems to fix the problem for us.  Thank you!