# Play framework 2: Error when trying to start application in production mode

Tags: frameworks, playframework-2.0

OS: Windows 7 64bit

java version: 1.7.0_17

javac Version: 1.7.0_17

I'm new to Play Framework, basically wanted to get a feel of everything.

There's a sample application called java/helloworld. Haven't changed anything and went on using the "start" command.

```
[helloworld] $ start

(Starting server. Type Ctrl+D to exit logs, the server will remain in background
)

Error occurred during initialization of VM
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.System.initializeSystemClass(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range:
 0
        at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.Win32FileSystem.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.FileSystem.getFileSystem(Native Method)
        at java.io.File.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.System.initializeSystemClass(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is anything to do with Play. It seems like you have encountered [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13913196/file-separator-java-7-option-causes-exceptionininitializererror), which looks to be a JVM bug on your flavour of Windows.

To run the sample applications in production mode, you may have to proceed as follows:

1. Run the `play stage` command (outside the Play console, just on the command line). The stage task is described [here](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/Production)
2. Add [this JVM argument](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14002403/926710) to the `target\start` script generated by the stage task, before then starting the application.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround add

```
 -Dfile.separator=\/
```

parameter to play.bat and build.bat.